# I navigate to blank page always in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to change screens in my flutter application which is called BMI calculator and the problem is whenever I try to go to new screen it doesn't work and It gives me black empty screen

[image]

and the code is

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return ResultsPage();
                }
              ),);
            },
```

this is the first screen and the following is the second screen

[image]

Comment: `Navigator.push()` function is an asynchronous function so you should be to use this: `onTap: () async {await Navigator.push(...);}`

Comment: The navigation Syntax looks correct to me just Make Sure the ResultsPage() Widget has a material Widget e.g Scaffold can you show whats there in your ResultsPage() widget and also check if theres any error in the debug console

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsPage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ResultsPage()),
        ),
```

Try like this